# Unexpected behavior of string reallocation

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, realloc

I have encountered a strange behavior of memory allocation with string-functions.

**Note**: right now i am told to ignore failure of the allocation operation.

My code is:

```
void string_reallocation(char *result, int result_length) {
    char *temp_result = malloc((strlen(result) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(temp_result, result);

    realloc(result, (result_length + 1) * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(result, temp_result);

    free(temp_result);
}
```

this function is called with iterations within a while loop:

```
    while (current_node != NULL) {
        current_value_to_string = current_node->toStringFunc(current_node->value);
        current_value_length = (int) strlen(current_value_to_string);
        current_length += current_value_length + arrow_length;

        string_reallocation(result, current_length);

        strcat(result, current_value_to_string);
        strcat(result, arrow);

        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
```

`current_node` is of type Node as follows:

```
typedef struct t_node {
    Element value;
    struct t_node *next;
    elementDestroy destroyFunc;
    elementCopy copyFunc;
    elementToString toStringFunc;
} *Node;
```

The thing is, for some reason, specifically on the third iteration the `free(temp_result);` fails with a segmentation fault.

I'm don't think that the while loop has anything to do with the segmentation fault but i put it here in case it does.

Comment: Try `result = realloc(result, (result_length + 1) * sizeof(char));`. GTG

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica now after the third iteration `result`'s value is gibberish.

Comment: Also, char *result has to be char **result as the address of char * gets overwritten only on the stack and you lose the new address returned by realloc after the function ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a biphasic solution, since you got to understand how to use `realloc()`, by checking on its prototype. Let's do just that first.

Change this:

```
realloc(result, (result_length + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

to this:

```
result = realloc(result, (result_length + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

since from the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/), we got for the prototype of this method:

> **Return value**: A pointer to the reallocated memory block, which may be
>   either the same as ptr or a new location.

---

Now, think about the scope of your variables (pointers). As @whozCraig commented, `result =` (in the corrected `realloc()`) assigns a value to an automatic variable. The original result passed in caller-side is unchanged, and now dangling. This has to be handled with an in/out arg or a function return result.

So what you could do, is to simply return that pointer, by changing this:

```
void string_reallocation(char *result, int result_length) {
```

to that:

```
char* string_reallocation(char *result, int result_length) {
  // ...
  return result;
}
```

and then change the call to this function, to this:

```
result = string_reallocation(result, current_length);
```

Comment: @WhozCraig I injected your comment to my answer, hope that's fine. Please take a look, and if anything is off, then let me know. Thanks!